# How to create objects dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

Im working with a library to create tables in react-pdf. And i want to fill it with api data. Is there a way of iterating inside the data{} and create various objects with data from api. Instead of sth like

```
data={[{firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith",country: "Australia"}]},
data={[{firstName: "Josh", lastName: "Pattison",country: "USA"}]}
```

have

```
data={[{firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith",country: "Australia"}],
      [{firstName: "Josh", lastName: "Pattison",country: "USA"}]
}
```

Code

```
{Data.attributes.map((details) => (
  <TableBody data={[
      {firstName:  details.attributes.filter(
        (x) => x.displayName === "first name"
      )[0].value, 
      lastName: details.attributes.filter(
        (x) => x.displayName === "last name"
      )[0].value, 
      country: details.attributes.filter(
        (x) => x.displayName === "country"
      )[0].value},
  
  ]}>
</TableBody>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.entries()` to get a 2D array of your object and use something like `forEach` or map to have loop over it and create the desired data shape:

```
const finalResult = {}

Object.entries(apiData).map(([key, value]) => {
   // do what ever you want here and fill your desired structure
})
```